# Database partial replication update consistency check

Tags: database, hash, replication, transmission

We have a custom database that is partially replicated from server to client, and then updated as new items come in. We send only the delta to update the client. To ensure robust operation, we'd like to send a consistency check (hash) of the entire subset the client should have together with the delta.

If we were sending the whole database, it would be easy to just keep a hash over the entire database. But since we're sending a subset that varies from client to client, this doesn't work. We need an efficient way to generate the hash for an arbitrary subset of the database without having to load all the actual items in the database subset each time.

Any suggestions for an efficient and elegant way to do this?

Thanks.